# angular options preflight request being interpreted as a route by codeigniter 4

Tags: routes, codeigniter-4, angular13, preflight

What is happening?

- When i submit a form in angular, a call is made to a codeigniter 4 backend. The following error occurs:

```
{
    "title": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
    "type": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Can't find a route for 'options: codeSnippets'.",
    "file": "/app/myapp/system/CodeIgniter.php",
    "line": 957,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/app/myapp/system/CodeIgniter.php",
            "line": 957,
            "function": "forPageNotFound",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/app/myapp/system/CodeIgniter.php",
            "line": 354,
            "function": "display404errors",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/app/myapp/public/index.php",
            "line": 67,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

This happens during the preflight phase of the request. I found out by creating an options request in postman.

what i want: I want the form to submit it's value's to the resource controller and store them in the database.
This is the relevant angular code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-code-snippet',
  templateUrl: './create-code-snippet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-code-snippet.component.scss']
})
export class CreateCodeSnippetComponent implements OnInit {
  
  title = new FormControl('');
  content = new FormControl('')
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  public  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      //Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  create() {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/codeSnippets',JSON.stringify({ title: this.title, content: this.content}),this.httpOptions)
  }

  send() {
    console.log('test')
    this.create().subscribe((data)=> console.log(data));
  }

}
```

And the codeigniter controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use App\Models\CodeSnippet as CodeSnippetModel;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;

class CodeSnippets extends ResourceController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    protected $modelName = 'App\Models\CodeSnippet';
    protected $format    = 'json';

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->respond($this->model->findAll());
    }

    public function create()
    {
       
        $CodeSnippetModel = new CodeSnippetModel();
        $data = [
            'title' => $this->request->getVar('title'),
            'content'  => $this->request->getVar('content'),
        ];
        $CodeSnippetModel->insert($data);
        //return $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(200)->setJSON( ['message' => 'testing'] );
        //return $this->respondCreated();
    }
}
```

I've tried intercepting the options request in a filter but somehow it doesn't get there. I can intercept it in the routes config file:

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();
if ($request->getMethod('options')) {
    var_dump('test');
}
```

I know i somehow have to return a 200 OK response and set these headers i think:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

Some relevant info is i'm running an angular 13 development server and am connecting that to a docker Codeigniter container with exposed ports on 8000. As said i can reach it no problem with postman and the data gets stored in DB the problem occurs when submitting the form from angular and when submitting an options request from postman.

Update:

After setting:

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

In config/routes.php

And placing this code in the corsfilter i made:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class CorsFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * Do whatever processing this filter needs to do.
     * By default it should not return anything during
     * normal execution. However, when an abnormal state
     * is found, it should return an instance of
     * CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response. If it does, script
     * execution will end and that Response will be
     * sent back to the client, allowing for error pages,
     * redirects, etc.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param array|null       $arguments
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
            } else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            } else {
            $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
            $allowed_domains = array(
                'http://localhost:4200'            
            );
            
            
            if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
            }
            
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
            header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
            header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
            
        if ($request->getMethod('options') === "OPTIONS") {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$origin}");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK CORS");
            die();
        }
    }    

    /**
     * Allows After filters to inspect and modify the response
     * object as needed. This method does not allow any way
     * to stop execution of other after filters, short of
     * throwing an Exception or Error.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface  $request
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @param array|null        $arguments
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I'm not getting the error on the preflight check anymore.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Thanks i will do that. I need to get some clarity on what some headers do and why this autoroute setting works before i can properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was setting:

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

in Config/Routes.php

Combined with supplying the right headers and a response of '200 Cors OK' Like this:

```
if ($request->getMethod('options') === "OPTIONS") {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$origin}");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK CORS");
            die();
        }
```

Implemented in a CorsFilter as shown in the Original Post.(OP)